# pdf to image in android programatically

Tags: android

How to convert a PDF file with a single page to an image in android.
Can anybody please share some code for this? I have tried jpedal and itext, but with both I am having a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I found a project on that loads a PDF then converts it to image that I think that will help you. See the following link:
[Android PDF viewer](http://support.leadtools.com/CS/forums/41907/ShowPost.aspx)

Hope this helps.